# BindableLayout no aparece

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Estoy comenzando con xamarin y buscando vi una propiedad de los StackLayout (BindableLayout) que a mi no me aparece. Alguien me podría decir el por qué?

Tengo la versión  4.6.0.800 de Xamarin Forms.

Comment: Como tratas de agregar BindableLayout ? agregalo a tu pregunta Mauricio.

Answer (score 0):

Desde la versión 3.4 de Xamarin.Forms esta presente [`BindableLayout`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindablelayout?view=xamarin-forms), de acuerdo con el [foro oficial de Xamarin](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/170344/bindablelayout-was-not-found-when-i-type-it-in-a-stacklayout) debes definirlo de esta forma dentro de `StackLayout`:

```
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding User.TopFollowers}"
             Orientation="Horizontal">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            //Aquí tu código.

        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```